# How to schedule an Airflow DAG every 5 minutes starting from 2nd minutes of the hour?

Tags: cron, airflow, airflow-2.x

I need to schedule my Airflow DAG to run on every 5 minutes, starting from 2nd minute of the hour. Sample execution times would be,

```
12:02 AM, 12:07 AM, 12:12 AM, 12:17 AM,... etc.
```

What would be the cron-like configuration for this requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an expression of `2/5 * * * *` seems to do the trick.

The “next” times with this expression in [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#2/5_*_*_*_*) line up nicely with what you are aiming for:

```
at 2023-01-16 13:57:00
then at 2023-01-16 14:02:00
then at 2023-01-16 14:07:00
then at 2023-01-16 14:12:00
then at 2023-01-16 14:17:00
```